# Como escrever o símbolo de porcentagem em uma string em Java?

Tags: java, string

Como fazer para a string aceitar o símbolo de porcentagem '`%`' ?

Comment: Tentou simplesmente escapar com \ ?

Comment: funcionou... estranho, tentei antes, e não tinha funcionado!!

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para escapar o `%` use duas porcentagens `%%`